# systemjs is unable to link and down load my new module

Tags: angular, npm, systemjs

I have created a angular module which is getting downloaded using npm as its private node module in my company registry

My systemjs always search it in my current directory with any extension even I set default extension as `js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your systemjs configuration holds all you mapping properly

Below is a systemjs confi which holds different angular2 modules as individual

```
modules and loads from different folders
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'src',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
      'ng2-pagination': 'npm:ng2-pagination/dist/ng2-pagination-bundle.js',

      //private modules
      'local': 'local/',
      'candi-services': 'npm:candi-services',
      'candi-loader': 'npm:candi-loader',
      'candi-global-search': 'npm:candi-global-search'

    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      defaultExtension: 'js',
      app: {
        main: 'app/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      local: {
        main: 'main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'candi-loader' : {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'candi-services' : {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
       'candi-global-search' : {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: make sure to check your folder structure

Comment: is systemjs understands other modules like es6, commonjs etc

Comment: yes. systemjs loader is understand make module system for both browser and nodejs